# Rails Using Edit action in a Show View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm trying to update an object in it's show view. I've been following railscasts [HABTM checkboxes](http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes-revised?view=asciicast).

Getting the following error:

> No route matches [PUT] "/accounts/4/edit"

Here is my form:

```
<%= form_for @account, :url => { :action => "edit"} do |form| %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag "account[checklist_ids][]", nil%>
    <% Checklist.all.each do |checklist| %>
        <%= check_box_tag "account[checklist_ids][]", checklist.id, @account.checklist_ids.include?(checklist.id) %>
        <%= checklist.task %><br/>
    <% end %><br/>
<%= form.submit "Update Checklist", class: 'btn' %>
<% end %>
```

/app/controllers/accounts_controller.rb

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  respond_to :html, :json

  def show
    @account = Account.find(params[:id])
    @notes = @account.notes.all
    @contacts = @account.contacts.all
  end


  def edit
    @account = Account.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @account = Account.find(params[:id])
    @account.update_attributes(params[:account])
    respond_with @account
  end
end
```

/app/models/account.rb

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :address, :city, :name, :phone, :state, :website, :zip, :contactname
  attr_accessible :conferences_attributes, :checklists_attributes
  has_many :notes, :dependent => :destroy 
  has_many :accountchecklists
  has_many :checklists, :through => :accountchecklists, :dependent => :destroy 
  has_many :contacts, :dependent => :destroy
  has_and_belongs_to_many :conferences
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :conferences
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :checklists
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed

```
<%= form_for @account, :url => { :action => "edit"} do |form| %>
```

change to

```
<%= form_for @account, :url => { :action => "update"} do |form| %>
```

and then I made the checklist_ids accessible since I was getting a can't mass assign checklist_ids

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible  :checklist_ids
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`<%= form_for @account, :url => { :action => "edit"} do |form| %>`

change to

`<%= form_for(@account) do |form| %>`